# What does a timeOut do (using html parsing with Jsoup)

Tags: java, html, timeout, jsoup

I am new to this, and I am writing a program that parses html from a Url:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com").timeout(600000).get();
```

What does the `.timeout(600000)` do?

Comment: https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html#timeout-int-

Answer (score 2):

Timeout sets timeout period for connection (in another words, the maximum time for which that client will wait for a response from server). Method parameter is in milliseconds.

Following are details from the jsoup [Connection javadoc](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html#timeout-int-).

> **Timeout:** 
>   Set the request timeouts (connect and read). If a timeout occurs, an
>   IOException will be thrown. The default timeout is 30 seconds (30,000
>   millis). A timeout of zero is treated as an infinite timeout. Note
>   that a read timeout is not the same as a maximum timeout. As long as
>   the connection is sending bytes at least every timeout seconds (e.g.
>   in the case of an infinite stream of data, or a slow large download),
>   the read timeout will not fire. This can be mitigated by using a
>   maximum download size (see maxBodySize(int)), or interrupting the
>   connecting thread after a max timeout.

Comment: BTW in jsoup 1.11.1 the timeout is now actually a total timeout, not just a read timeout. I.e. an infinite stream with periodic output will get timed out correctly now.